# How to properly send mutliple http requests to different servers at a certain time?

Tags: javascript

My current problem is that I have to send MULTIPLE http requests that are stored individually in an array to MULTIPLE servers at a certain time:

**EX:** array[0] = "http://.../", array[1] = "http://.../"

Executing the code at a certain time is easy with setInterval(checktime), but the issue is a "for" loop used to iterate through the server commands being sent not meshing with the setInterval function causing the "for" loop to run through and only send the http to the **LAST** server. Every server request prior to it is skipped.

Here is my JS code:

```js
function sendHttpCmds(stbnum){
 var stb_num = stbnum;
 var date = [];
 var xmlhttp = [];
 
 //loop to iterate through the different stb's(servers)
 for(var i = 0; i < stb_num; i++){

  var http = stb_prop.http_list[i];
  var httpLength = http.length;
  var firstTime = 1;
  var lastIPcmd = stb_prop.ip_list[i];

  function xmlsend(cmd){
            xmlhttp[i].open("GET",http[cmd],false);
            xmlhttp[i].send(null);
     }
     

  setInterval(function(){
   date[i] = new Date();

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp[i] =new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp[i] =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   if(firstTime === 1){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + date[i].getHours() + ':' + date[i].getMinutes();
   }

   if(date[i].getHours() === 14 && date[i].getMinutes() === 20 && firstTime === 1){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br><b>The report log for STB #'+(i+1)+' is being collected. Please wait:</b><br>';
    //insert progress bar here
    firstTime = 0;
          
          for(cmd = 0; cmd < httpLength; cmd++){
             (function(cmd){
               setTimeout(function(){
                xmlsend(cmd);

                if(cmd === (httpLength-1)){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        xmlhttp[i].open("GET","http://"+lastIPcmd+":8080/remote/processKey?key=poweroff&hold=keyPress",false);
                        xmlhttp[i].send(null);
                        document.body.innerHTML += '<br>The report log for STB #'+(i+1)+' has been collected! <br>';
                    },180000); //set delay to send power off command at 5 minutes                        
                }
               },2000*cmd);//set base delay ~1000-2500 ms
              }(cmd));
          }
      }
  },5000)//check every 5 seconds for the correct time
 }
}
```

If anyone could enlighten me on how to properly do this that would be great! Another method I was thinking of would be firing 1 http request to 1 server, wait for it to finish then fire the next 1 to the next server, but I do not know how to do that either :\

Comment: Just glancing at that it looks like a variable scope nightmare. Trying to understand it.

Comment: What does `stb_prop` hold?

Comment: It is a variable scope nightmare, I was able to hammer out all the major scope issues. The big thing is that the "for" loop is not playing nice with the "setInterval" since the JS still runs past the "setInterval" and iterates through the "for", by the time the time matches i = max value making only shoot http to the last server.

Comment: function stbProperties(){
 this.ip_list = [];
 this.model_list = [];
 this.key_list = [];
 this.http_list = [];
}

var stb_prop = new stbProperties();

It is just an object that contains the various arrays of ip addresses, models, and httpcmds to be sent.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the cmd is being changed but still being used in the interval. Something as simple as `var cmd2 = cmd;` at the start of your for loop will work. Then inside the for loop change the `cmd` to `cmd2`. Thus setting a local value for that loop. I'm not sure that will work but I'm pretty sure that is where the problem is happening.